# what is the use of side effect distinct Until Changed in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY id DESC")
    fun getAllTasks() : Flow<List<Task>>
    fun getAllTasksDistinctUntilChanged() = getAllTasks()
```

> .distinctUntilChanged()

I don't know the use of that side effect after a long search please someOne explain it in easy way.

Answer (score 0):

distintUntilChanged operator filters subsequent repetitions of the same value.

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit){
    val myFlow:Flow<Int> = listOf(1,2,2,3,2,4,5,5,5,5,1,1,2).asFlow()
    myFlow
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .onEach { item:Int->
            println("Num: $item:Int")
        }
        .launchIn(this)
}
```

this snippet prints out

```
I/System.out: Num: 1
I/System.out: Num: 2
I/System.out: Num: 3
I/System.out: Num: 2
I/System.out: Num: 4
I/System.out: Num: 5
I/System.out: Num: 1
I/System.out: Num: 2
```

However if you apply to flow<List> that returns one item which is a List of Task in your question nothing will happen.

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
    myFlow()
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .onEach { list: List<Int> ->
            println("List: $list")
        }
        .launchIn(this)
}

private fun myFlow(): Flow<List<Int>> {
    return flow {
        emit(listOf(1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2))
    }
}
```

prints out

```
I/System.out: List: [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2]
```